# How to enable/disable Cloudfront logging from CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In `DistributionConfig` we have the logging configuration:

```yaml
Logging:
  IncludeCookies: 'true'
  Bucket: !Sub '${BucketName}-logs.s3.amazonaws.com'
  Prefix: 'CF'
```

However is there a config parameter to enable/disable logging, similar to the option in the AWS Console?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such parameter for disabling logging in the 
`AWS::CloudFront::Distribution DistributionConfig` resource.

It is the presence of the `Logging` property in the resource definition that enables logging. To disable logs, you can simply remove the `Logging` property section from your resource, and update the stack.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-distributionconfig.html

Answer (score -1):

Adding the attribute - `"Enabled": "false"` inside the `Logging` object will disable logging.

**Here is the change that can be applied to the cloud-formation template:**

```
"Logging" : {
    "IncludeCookies" : "false",
    "Bucket" : "s3-bucket-name",
    "Prefix" : "logging-prefix",
    "Enabled": "false"
}
```

**More information:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudfront.html

Comment: It gives me 

Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/DistributionConfig/Logging}: [Enabled]]

Comment: [`Logging`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-logging.html) does not have an `Enabled` property